# Return PASS or FAIL for FITSharp 'Include' pages

Tags: testing, automated-tests, fitnesse, fitsharp

I have a test set up in FITSharp that contains an 'include page from current' section as shown below.

The main test keeps passing even when the 'included' test page fails (when expanded).

Is there a way to force FITNesse to take into account the results of 'included' tests.

Here is my test:

**|include | page from current | ..\testFileName.html |**

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug.  I've opened an issue: https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/issues/118